# Eclipse Issue: P/tag_query, does not match outer scope rule

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

The eclipse platform for RCP product was upgraded from 3.6.2 to 4.6.3. The below code was working fine with 3.6.2:

```
public static ConfigTagService getTagService(MethodConfiguration config) {
    delegate = ConfigurationHelper.getDelegate();   
    thisConfig = config;
    if (delegate instanceof ConfigHelperDelegate) {
        configTagService = ((ConfigHelperDelegate) delegate).getTagService_(thisConfig);                    
        return configTagService;
        }
    return null;
}
```

But after upgrade I am getting issue with this code and subsequent calls to below line throws exception:

```
folder.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

The detailed stack trace is:

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of view".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to beginRule: P/tag_query, does not match outer scope rule: com.eclipse.rmc.authoring.ui.providers.ConfigurationContentProvider$BatchSimilarSchedulingRule@f9cfe23e
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.illegalPush(ThreadJob.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.push(ThreadJob.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1586)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.tag.internal.TagService.initialize(TagService.java:546)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.tag.internal.TagService.<init>(TagService.java:293)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.tag.AbstractTagService.newInstance(AbstractTagService.java:42)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.ConfigTagService.newTagService(ConfigTagService.java:82)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.ConfigTagService.setConfig(ConfigTagService.java:72)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.ConfigHelperDelegate.getTagService_(ConfigHelperDelegate.java:387)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.ConfigHelperDelegate.getTagService(ConfigHelperDelegate.java:175)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.configuration.DefaultElementRealizer.addExtraToManyFeatureValues(DefaultElementRealizer.java:76)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.library.configuration.DefaultElementRealizer.addExtraFeatureValues(DefaultElementRealizer.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.configuration.ConfigurationHelper.calculateFeature(ConfigurationHelper.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.configuration.ConfigurationHelper.calc0nFeatureValue_(ConfigurationHelper.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.configuration.ConfigurationHelper.calc0nFeatureValue(ConfigurationHelper.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.configuration.ConfigurationHelper.calc0nFeatureValue(ConfigurationHelper.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.configuration.ConfigurationFilter.getChildren(ConfigurationFilter.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.edit.internal.TngAdapterFactoryImpl$FilterItemProvider.getChildren_(TngAdapterFactoryImpl.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.epf.library.edit.internal.TngAdapterFactoryImpl$FilterItemProvider.getChildren(TngAdapterFactoryImpl.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.provider.AdapterFactoryContentProvider.getChildren(AdapterFactoryContentProvider.java:175)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.authoring.ui.providers.ConfigurationContentProvider.fetchChildren(ConfigurationContentProvider.java:168)
    at com.eclipse.rmc.authoring.ui.providers.ConfigurationContentProvider$DeferredItem.fetchDeferredChildren(ConfigurationContentProvider.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I find the similar issue at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/442274/ and applied the solution to the causing issue as:

```
Job job = new Job("New job for tag query") {
    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        configTagService = ((ConfigHelperDelegate) delegate).getTagService_(thisConfig);
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
job.schedule();
```

With this fix, I do not get any exception and it works fine. However, for the large library, this the publish freezes with this fix. Could you please suggest alternative to avoid freeze issue?

Comment: Why are you still using a release which is now 5 years and 14 releases old? What is ConfigTagService? What "publish"? None of that is core Eclipse so what other Eclipse projects are you using?

Comment: Freezes are caused by code running in the UI thread. Are you sure this needs to be run in the UI thread?